# Extender la columnas de una BD con registros

Tags: base-de-datos, tablas

Teniendo en cuenta que las cosas cambian conforme pasa el tiempo, una de las dudas más grandes que recorre mi cabeza en este momento es: qué debería hacer si deseo cambiar la lógica de mi negocio para guardar más información sobre una entidad especifica, ya que esta deberá ser persistida y ya existen registros posteriores: ¿Qué sucede con los registros ya existentes?

La todos los nuevos campos deberán permitir null para que los registros anteriores no rompan la bd?

Y algo más controversial: que hay si necesito eliminar una de las columnas? Debo ir directamente a la base de datos, antes de hacer deploy de las nuevas características, y ejecutar una query que elimite todos esos registros para no causar problemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es común que sistemas que ya están en producción sufran de actualizaciones, tanto por mejoras/evolución del software mismo, como por cambios en el funcionamiento de las empresas/industrias y el marco legal que las regula.

Con esto, las estructuras de base de datos evolucionan también. La manera de actualizar/evolucionar una estructura de base de datos varía según el motor de base de datos y las herramientas que estén a tu disposición.

Si hablamos de bases de datos relacionales, más allá de los mecanismos utilizados, al final, será sentencias *DDL* las que cambien las estructuras.

Cuando se crean columnas nuevas, se pueden tomar varias estrategias:

- Crear las columnas `nullable`, de manera que no haya conflicto con registros que ya existan en la base de datos.
- Crear columnas nuevas con un valor default y el atributo `not null` establecido.
- Crear columnas nuevas como `nullable`, luego realizar alguna sentencia para *derivar* el valor que deben tener y posteriormente cambiar la definición de la columna como `not null`.

Como parte de la evolución, también es común que se creen tablas nuevas, se eliminen columnas que ya son obsoletas en el nuevo modelo y se eliminen también tablas por la misma razón.

Acá también se verán casos donde, luego de crear una tabla nueva, se *voltea* información desde una tabla existente para llenarla y luego se elimina la tabla existente. Esto es común cuando la estructura ha sufrido procesos de re-ingeniería.

Dependiendo de las capacidades del motor de base de datos, estas operaciones podrían llevarse a cabo en el contexto de una transacción, con lo cual, si algo falla durante la evolución de las estructuras, aplicas un `rollback` y dejas todo como si nada hubiese pasado.

Si el motor no lo permite, la única manera de ir a la segura es realizar una copia o copia de seguridad y si algo falla, restaurar desde la copia.